# Create a dynamic or variable drop down menu in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I have an excel spreadsheet containing a great number of people who work in my company. I'm required (among other things) to create a field that contains the role of each person in their team, which has to be chosen from a drop down menu. 
No problem so far. I write the options in a column on another sheet, name the range and create the drop down using Data Validation. 
If I change the entries in the range, naturally, the options in the drop down change. What I want is for the fields that have been already filled with an option from the drop down to also change.
For example: if John Doe has the role of 'Team Coordinator' already selected and I change the 'Team Coordinator' entry to 'Team Supervisor', nothing happens to John Doe's role. It only changes the option in the drop down. How could I update John Doe's role?

VBA solutions are welcome if it's not possible simply within Excel.

Comment: No idea what you are looking for, since you didn't post any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this in Excel.  To save a few bits of data on the internet, check out this website which goes into detail on the possibilities of Data Validation.

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html